# jmeter capture all request and response headers a single http request triggers

Tags: jmeter

In actual browser when I send one HTTP request for a webpage, in Fiddler I see this starts a chain of HTTP requests and a response for each one of them.

How can I capture this chain of request and response headers in jmeter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should be able to record your browser actions in JMeter using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).
- Check this step by step [tutorial](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- Add a [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) under [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) to see the request and response headers the browser sends.

[image]

- While recording, you can safely exclude all the static files (like css/img/js etc) from being recorded by updating below section.

[image]

- While playing back the recorded script, ensure that below option is selected in the HTTP Sampler to download the static files (if required).

[image]